# React native TextInput unexpectedly lose focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textinput

Does anyone know why the TextInput automatically blurs when I move it down, but not up?

Currently, I have given all the TextInput unique keys that doesn't depend on the index. With the unique keys, React would only move the component up/down without removing it from the UI then add it back afterwards.

Normally, the TextInput should not lose focus during the process of moving up/down. It worked correctly when moving up, but not when moving down. I am still unsure why it loses focus when moving down.

I have tried re-focusing the input back after it's blurred but it doesn't look well because the keyboard toggling up and down when it's blurred and focused.

Does anyone know any solution to this problem, or maybe the cause of it?

This is the [video recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IyHZuknr-8sPBGtOJHZWJ_MUWQgxVA-p/view?usp=sharing) of what it's like. You can also check my code below.

```
import {TextInput, InputAccessoryView, View, Button} from 'react-native'

function TextInputTest() {
    const [blocks, setBlocks] = React.useState([{id: '0.10672728769404416', text: 'Apple'}, {id: '0.31070739302450745', text: 'Candy'}, {id: '0.25926686382358066', text: 'Banana'}])
    const moveUp = ({index}) => {
        setBlocks(b => {
            const arr = [...b] 
            const ind = index-1
            if(ind>=0) {
                const x = arr[index]
                arr[index] = arr[ind]
                arr[ind] = x
            }
            return arr
        })
    }
    const moveDown = ({index}) => {
        setBlocks(b => {
            const arr = [...b] 
            const ind = index+1
            if(ind<arr.length) {
                const x = arr[index]
                arr[index] = arr[ind]
                arr[ind] = x
            }
            return arr
        })
    }
    return (
        <View style={{padding: 20}}>
            {
                blocks.map((val, i) => (
                    <TextInputBlock
                        initialValue={val.text}
                        key={val.id}
                        index={i}
                        canMoveDown={i+1<blocks.length}
                        canMoveUp={i-1>=0}
                        moveDown={()=>moveDown({index: i})}
                        moveUp={() => moveUp({index: i})}
                    />
                ))
            }
        </View>
    )
}

function TextInputBlock({index=0, initialValue='', moveUp=()=>{}, moveDown=()=>{}, canMoveUp=false, canMoveDown=false}) {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue)
    const onChangeText = t => setValue(t)

    return (
        <>
            <TextInput inputAccessoryViewID={`${index}`} multiline autoFocus style={{backgroundColor: 'white', minWidth: '100%', padding: 8}} placeholder='Enter some text' {...{onBlur, onFocus, value, onChangeText}}/>
            <InputAccessoryView nativeID={`${index}`}>
                <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white', borderTopWidth: 1, borderTopColor:'#ddd', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                    <Button title="Move Up" onPress={moveUp} disabled={!canMoveUp}/>
                    <Button title="Move Down" onPress={moveDown} disabled={!canMoveDown}/>
                </View>
            </InputAccessoryView>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: One solution that you can try is with the useRef hook, you can manually set the focus of the TextField with it every time you move the element down

Comment: It's possible to do that. However, as I mentioned in the post, it doesn't look good. The keyboard will hide, then show again (sliding down, then slide up). Thanks anyway!